# whats the difference between cache & http cache "reverse proxy"

Tags: php, caching, reverse-proxy

am having a bit of difficulty understanding the difference between the normal cache "memory,file,db,etc.." and the http caching "reverse proxy".

**Example.**

lets say i have a page divided into 3 parts.

- movies
- games
- apps

and when i retrieve those parts from the db, i cache each part in its own key & when a new data is entered to any of those parts i flush the cache and remake it including the new data, so now each part will only update if there is something new was added.

on the other hand the http caching have something call `ESI` which u can include page partials that have a different cache life span from the main page which is perfect but

why would i need to use it ? 
or what is the advantage over the first method ?

**Edit**

> - this is slimier to what i was after but still, why would u use/continue to use the reverse proxy over the below ?
>
> https://laracasts.com/series/russian-doll-caching-in-laravel
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/3b16wr/caching_final_html_from_view/
>   https://github.com/laracasts/matryoshka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reverse proxy cache has a few benefits:

- Requests served by the proxy never hit your webserver. It's typically
  cheaper/easier to scale out your proxy servers (e.g. by using
  commercial providers like Akamai) than to scale out your
  webserver(s).
- This means you can survive traffic spikes and denial of
  service attacks with much less stress.
- It also means you can serve
  traffic that's not close to your origin webserver much faster - if
  your site serves a global audience, latency can have a big impact on
  your perceived response time.
- You can also take your webserver off line, e.g. for upgrades, without affecting your end users.

Drawbacks of reverse proxy caching:

- It's an additional layer of architecture, which brings complexity, maintenance, administration etc.
- It may also require additional costs (most sites have separate infrastructure for the reverse proxy servers, or use a commercial CDN provider).
- Your solution design needs to manage cache invalidation between even more layers - this can easily become complex and error prone.
- This, in turn, means that debugging and testing the solution can be very hard. If the QA team report an incorrect page, you need to be able to find out where the item was served from - reverse proxy, application cache, database?

Comment: dam, that sound more complicated than i thought, thanx.